# What are the objects called that are not business domain objects?

Tags: object-oriented, domain-model

In object oriented software engineering, *domain*- or *business objects* are those objects dealing with the [domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model). What are the other objects called that or **not** part of the domain model? *Helper objects*? *System objects*? Are they sub-divided into different other denominations? What would be examples of each?

Comment: Why the downvotes? :( It's a simple question about vocabulary. I tried Google but it didn't give me any useful results.

Comment: "Library" or "Framework" come to mind, though those words refer to the _grouping_ of objects and not to specific objects.

Comment: Framework. Platform-specific. Data access layer. IO layer. Parallels. You name it. But the way you phrased it, it seems that "every class is either Pizza or Not Pizza", and this is a bad definition. Domain model classes work with the *Business* domain. IO classes deal with *IO* domain. DAL classes deal with *Data Access* domain. To each problem domain it's own definition.

Comment: What is the opposite of "ice cream?"  Or, if you prefer a more "systemic" example, what is the opposite of "food?"  Part of the problem is your vocabulary: "opposite" doesn't mean "not this," it means "that which is diametrically different."  The opposite of forward is reverse.  The opposite of a green traffic light is a red traffic light.

Comment: There is nothing opinion based about the answer to this question, it is just basic OO theory. When OO emerged, the today somewhat obsolete theory spoke of "components", as being parts of a system. In addition to the Problem Domain Components you had your Human Interaction Components (HIC), Task Management Components (TMC) and Data Management Components (DMC). And then there were "agents" that string it all together, that script the program into action. Today only PDC seems to have survived. The others are somewhat arbitrary. The PDC models the world, the rest is just plumbing.

Comment: I really don't get why this should be opinion-based? Granted, "opposite" might not be the right term. Bear with me i'm not a native English speaker. So is there no common term for the objects not being part of the domain model?